# Flutter : Libraries conflict with AndroidX (ImagePicker & Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, androidx

my question is ... I am coding a new app that needs both image picker and Google maps features

my problem is ... image picker condition that I should integrate my app settings to Android X while Google Maps showing problems with Android X.

I read some solution that suggested that I should downgrade my app to under Android X in order to use Google Maps Library ... which what I did

Current Situation : 
App not compatible with Android X
Google Maps works correctly 
Image Picker Not Work and showing Error in Running the app

Any help will be great ... Best Regard

-------- Edit (Error) --------

when I didn't enable the Android X Compatibility

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
    > Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

    * Try:
    Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 9s
    *******************************************************************************************
    The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
    See  for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
    *******************************************************************************************
    Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

____________________________________________________
```

**When I Enable Android X Compatibility :**
    Error :

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\_______PharX\___FlutterApp - 2\pharx\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.

> Configure project :flutter_launch
WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of google_maps_flutter will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_launch' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

* Try:
Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 59s
  Command: D:\_______PharX\___FlutterApp - 2\pharx\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: Put android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
    lines in android/gradle.properties file this may solve your problem

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @ParthPatel Thanks ...  I already do that (and now I add the error log to my question)

Comment: @Speed now I added the error log to my question ... Thanks

Comment: can you please add build.gradle files?

Comment: It says `The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.` So go to where your kotlin plugin is in your gradle file and update the version to the latest one